# Spring Security : Forcing apis on https using requires-channel attributes

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security

I am very new in Spring framework and currently I am working on Spring + Maven project and in my project there are lot's of APIs and I need to run/works few APIs on https only and they should not run with http.

I did some finding around this I found we can we do this very easily by using spring security **requires-channel** attributes.

Here are the few entries which made for requires channel in pom.xml and spring security files.

pom.xml entries

```
<properties>
<spring.security.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Added security related entries in spring-context.xml file

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="**/MyTesting"
    requires-channel="https" />

<security:authentication-manager>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

After adding this entry I tried to hit http://localhost:8080/MyTesting an it works to me after adding requires-channel="https". I tried to find around this but I am not able to get any useful link. Please check above entries and correct me what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your spring-config.xml file also here

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is incorrect. You can use the following as an exact match:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/MyTesting"
    requires-channel="https" />
```

**NOTE**: Spring Security ignores the context root when matching URLs so you do not need to account for it.

If you want to match all URLs that end with /MyTesting then you can use:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**/MyTesting"
    requires-channel="https" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is still is not working to me.